# Is there a solution for these equations?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Could someone please help me solve this problem? I want to be able to determine if  in the following  separate problems the real numbers can be expressed  as indicated $$2\sqrt{2}=\frac{\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}}{d}\pm\frac{\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}}{d}$$ and $$7=\frac{\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}}{d}\pm\frac{\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}}{d}$$  where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and if so is there just one, or are there more solutions? I have squared the LHS and RHS to see where that would lead me but to no avail. Many thanks.

Comment: By using the $\pm$ sign, you mean that the number can be expressed by either a sum or difference of the two fractions, but not necessarily by both, correct?

Comment: If there are no restrictions on $a,b,c,d$ one can find many solutions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: The restriction is where $a,b,c,d$ are integers...

Comment: @anorton that is correct the number can either be a sum or a difference of the two fractions or both I guess if there can be more than one solution.

Comment: Yes, that was in the post, but I meant further restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if they were NOT separate problems,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{57+28\sqrt{2}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{57-28\sqrt{2}}}{2} = 7,\qquad
\frac{\sqrt{57+28\sqrt{2}}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{57-28\sqrt{2}}}{2} = 2\sqrt{2} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $(7+2\sqrt{2})^2 = a+b\sqrt{2}$ and then $a,b,c=2,d=2$ is a solution for the first equation with "+" and the second equation with "-".

Comment: I don’t see how  $$2\sqrt{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{2}}}{2}$$ if that is what you are saying for  first equation since the second part of the RHS is a complex number.

Comment: No, $a,b$ are computed in the first step, and are not $2$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, take for example $a=4$, $b=2$, $c=4$, $d=1$.

Or else take $a=3$, $b=2$, $c=2$, $d=1$.

There are infinitely many other choices. In this case, one could describe them all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to come up with a set of solutions. $2\sqrt{2} =\sqrt{8}$ and the number $8$ can be calculated an infinite number of ways. For example $7+1$; $6+2$; $5+3$; $4+4$; $3+5$; $2+6$; $1+7$; $9-1$; $10-2$.... So let’s say we want to compute$$ \sqrt{100-92}$$  we can construct the following quadratic equation from this $$x^2-100x+\frac{92^2}{4}=0$$ The solutions to this quadratic are $$50+8\sqrt{6}$$ and $$50-8\sqrt{6}$$ Because we want the $\sqrt{8}$ we take the square roots of each of the solutions for the result$$\sqrt{50+8\sqrt{6}}-\sqrt{50-8\sqrt{6}}=2\sqrt{2}$$
Likewise with $$ \sqrt{7+1}$$  we can construct the following quadratic equation from this $$x^2-7x+\frac{1^2}{4}=0$$ The solutions to this quadratic are $$\frac{7+4\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ and $$\frac{7-4\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ Because we want the $\sqrt{8}$ we take the square roots of each of the solutions for the result$$\frac{\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{14-8\sqrt{3}}}{2}=2\sqrt{2}$$
So it appears as has been stated in other answers there are infinite solutions. The same could be done with the equation $$7=\frac{\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}}{d}\pm\frac{\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}}{d}$$ using combinations that equal $\sqrt{49}$.